# Changing class attribute in JS for loop stops after 8 iterations

Tags: javascript

Total coding noob here. I got this HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="display.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="SentenceInline()">Sentences = linline</button><br>
<button type="button" onclick="SentenceBlock()">Sentences = block</button></p>
<span class="sentence" id="first-p1-s1">Span 1</span>
<span class="sentence" id="first-p1-s2">Span 2</span>
…
<span class="sentence" id="first-p1-s9">Span 9</span>
<span class="sentence" id="first-p1-s10">Span 10</span>
<span class="sentence" id="first-p1-s11">Span 11</span>
<span class="sentence" id="first-p1-s12">Span 12</span>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

…and this code in diplay.js:

```js
function SentenceInline() {ChangeClassAttributes('sentence','inline');}
function SentenceBlock() {ChangeClassAttributes('sentence','block');}

function ChangeClassAttributes(FindClass,ChangeAttribute) {
var ClassToStyle = document.getElementsByClassName(FindClass);
for (let i = 0; i < FindClass.length; i++) { ClassToStyle[i].style.display = ChangeAttribute;}}
```

Clicking the `Sentences = block` button will change the display attribute of spans with class `sentence` for the first 8 `<span>` elements, then it stops. The remaining spans stay inline.

Can someone point out what I’m doing wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `FindClass.length` as the limit of your loop. `FindClass` is the first argument of your `ChangeClassAttributes` which is string `sentence`... which has a length of 8 :)

To fix this you'll need to change your loop to look something like this

```js
for (let i = 0; i < ClassToStyle.length; i++) {
    ClassToStyle[i].style.display = ChangeAttribute;
}
```